# Fluent NHibernate release plans

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

Fluent NHibernate's build server at
http://teamcity.codebetter.com/viewType.html?buildTypeId=bt9&tab=buildTypeStatusDiv
features 1.3 and 2.0 builds. Are there plans for a release of FNH 1.3? Is FNH 1.3 considered stable against NH 3.2?

Comment: there is already a 1.3 alpha in the wild which is usable with NH 3.2 but not yet stable/released. It has at least one Regression i know of. However i don't know if there is a release planned

Comment: @Firo thanks, I guess we will have to wait and see what happens.

Comment: if you need it now, grab the source and compile with NH 3.2